# Getting clusters of rows close together in time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table basically like so

```
   ID   |  ItemID  |       Start        |         End        |
---------------------------------------------------------------
    1       234      10/20/09 8:34:22      10/20/09 8:35:10
    2       274      10/20/09 8:35:30      10/20/09 8:36:27
    3       272      10/21/09 12:15:00     10/21/09 12:17:00
    4       112      10/21/09 12:20:14     10/21/09 12:21:21
    5       15       10/21/09 12:22:39     10/21/09 12:24:15
```

There are two "clusters" of entries here, 1-2 and 3-5 separated by a gap in time, specifically > 30 minutes is what I'm interested in.

What I would like is the first and last rows of the cluster of entries. This is fairly easy to achieve by retrieving all the rows and looping through them in order of start time, but I'd like to have it in SQL if possible.

I'm using SQL Server 2008, thanks.

Edit:

Each row would contain

```
  first.* , last.*
```

where first is the first row in the cluster and last is the last row.

the results of this table would be

```
    1       234      10/20/09 8:34:22      10/20/09 8:35:10           2       274      10/20/09 8:35:30      10/20/09 8:36:27
    3       272      10/21/09 12:15:00     10/21/09 12:17:00          5       15       10/21/09 12:22:39     10/21/09 12:24:15
```

Comment: What *exact* result set would you like please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this out:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (ID int, ItemID int, StartD datetime, EndD datetime)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1,234,'10/20/09 8:34:22' ,'10/20/09 8:35:10' )
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,274,'10/20/09 8:35:30' ,'10/20/09 8:36:27' )
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3,272,'10/21/09 12:15:00','10/21/09 12:17:00')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (4,112,'10/21/09 12:20:14','10/21/09 12:21:21')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (5,15 ,'10/21/09 12:22:39','10/21/09 12:24:15')

;WITH AggValues AS
(SELECT
     MAX(ID) AS MaxID, COUNT(ID) AS CountOf, MIN(ID) AS MinID
     FROM @YourTable
)
, NumberRows AS
(SELECT --generate a first row to help get a range
     0 AS ID, a.StartD-1 AS StartD, a.EndD-1 AS EndD, 0 AS RowNumber
     FROM @YourTable a
         INNER JOIN AggValues dt ON a.ID=dt.MinID
 UNION
 SELECT --get all actual rows
     ID, StartD, EndD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
     FROM @YourTable
 UNION
 SELECT --generate a last row to help get a range
     dt2.MaxID+1 AS ID, a.StartD+1 AS StartD, a.EndD+1 AS EndD, dt2.CountOf+1 AS RowNumber
     FROM @YourTable a
         INNER JOIN AggValues dt2 ON a.ID=dt2.MaxID
)
, FindGaps AS
(SELECT
     a.ID,DATEDIFF(minute,b.StartD,a.EndD) AS Diff, a.RowNumber, c.RowNumber AS PreviousRowNumber
     FROM NumberRows                 a
         LEFT OUTER JOIN NumberRows  b ON a.RowNumber=b.RowNumber+1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN NumberRows  c ON a.RowNumber-1=c.RowNumber
)
, Gaps AS
(SELECT
     f.ID,f.RowNumber, f.PreviousRowNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS GapRowNumber
     FROM FindGaps f
     WHERE f.Diff>30
)
, Results AS
(SELECT
     g.ID,n.ID AS IDEnd
     FROM Gaps                       g
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Gaps        x ON g.GapRowNumber+1=x.GapRowNumber
         LEFT OUTER JOIN NumberRows  n ON x.PreviousRowNumber=n.RowNumber
     WHERE n.ID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    a.*,b.*
    from Results                      r
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @YourTable    a ON r.ID=a.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @YourTable    b ON r.IDEnd=b.ID
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID          ItemID      StartD                  EndD                    ID          ItemID      StartD                  EndD
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           234         2009-10-20 08:34:22.000 2009-10-20 08:35:10.000 2           274         2009-10-20 08:35:30.000 2009-10-20 08:36:27.000
3           272         2009-10-21 12:15:00.000 2009-10-21 12:17:00.000 5           15          2009-10-21 12:22:39.000 2009-10-21 12:24:15.000

(2 row(s) affected)
```